# QT GUI does not appear over X11 forwarding

Tags: qt, x11-forwarding

I am attempting to run a QT widgets GUI application over ssh x11 forwarding from a linux machine to a windows machine but the app never appears.  I can see the process running on top, and in other setups I can also launch it with vscode and step debug it but in both instances there is nothing.

Simple tests with things like xeyes, firefox or codium do work and show up, some laggier than others.

Is x11 forwarding of QT applications possible or am I missing a configuration?

Comment: Possibly a silly question but... are you sure the Qt app is using x11 rather than something like, say, wayland?

Comment: That's probably true.   Unfortunately I'm pretty ignorant on this topic but will look into if there is something I can change to make it work.  If you happen to know how I would appreciate it.

Comment: Turns out that it's an issue with the QT application using somewhat modern OpenGL which is incompatible with x11 forwarding.

Comment: @Klypto so what did you do?

Comment: Given the size of the application there is nothing I or the teams can do about it so debugging for linux GUI's has to be done on physical machines instead of over the network.